# Can't use Nuxt custom Layout

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a NuxtJs application. I have a default layout that consists of a header and a footer that I use in most of my pages. I have one page that is a form that should not have a header but just a footer so I created a footer.vue file in the layouts directory that contains a slot for the page and a footer. the problem is that I can not get the page to use the just the footer layout. It either just uses the default layout or overlays the footer layout around the default layout.

here is the layouts/footer.vue:

```
<template>
  
    <div>
      <div class="content-wrapper flex-grow">
        <slot></slot>
        
      </div>
  
      <footer class="bg-teal-700">
        <img src="../assets/static/slogan.jpeg" class="footer-image" />
      </footer>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <style scoped>

  
  .footer-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
  }
  
  .content-wrapper {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
  </style>
```

in the page that I would like to use the footer layout I am unable to use this layout and the default layout keeps on being applied to this page.  have tried using the following in the script ags of the page

```
  export default {
    layout: 'footer',
    data() {
//.....
```

but the default layout still gets used on the page. after trying a few different approaches I have this code in my page now:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout name="footer">
  
   .....

  </NuxtLayout>
  </template>
  
  <script>
// ....
  
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
      // ...
      };
    },
    methods: {
// ....
    },
  };
  </script>
```

with this approach the footer layout does get applied but is overlayed by the default layout. so now there are two footers below each other(one from the default layout and one from the footer layout ) and also still a header (from the default layout). How can make this page use just the footer layout and?